# how to add functionality of choose_all and remove_all functionality for a model in django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin

[image]
I need to add the **Choose all** and **Remove all** functionality to one of the django model in the admin view. but not finding any documentation.

I am creating Food table:

```
<group1->
name:vegetarian

food 
----
vegetables
nuts
greens
chicken
egg


<group2->
name: non-veg

food 
----
vegetables
nuts
greens
chicken
egg
```

like above i need to choose the food-items and create a group. i want to display like groups option with choose_all/remove_all options.

Comment: please share model code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred the official django code for Groups. followed the same, and it just worked great.
Here is how i did.

```
class FoodPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.url_name)


class FoodGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(FoodPermission, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

In the admin.py.

The following code is copied from official django source and just changed class name and commented one line.

```
class FoodGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ("name",)
    ordering = ("name",)
    filter_horizontal = ("permissions",)


admin.site.register(FoodGroup, FoodGroupAdmin)
```

## with those changed everything worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use FilteredSelectMultiple widget in ModelForm.

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    food = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Food.objects.all(),
        widget=widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(verbose_name='Food', is_stacked=False)
    )
    ...
```